# iOS app not taking up entire screen in iOS 12 or 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an old iOS app last built on iOS 8. When the app runs on iOS 10 or higher on larger phones the view doesn't take up the entire screen, there is a black bar on the top and bottom of the screen. In the past, Apple would just expand the app so it was stretched a little.

Not sure how to fix this? I am sure there has to be an expand setting or something? I believe it has to do with setting a Launch Screen, but not sure where to set that or how to? I do have a LaunchScreen.storyboard in my files.

I have tried multiple things to fix the issue, but nothing seems to work?

Also, not sure if it is related, but the Navigation Item (deprecated?) was once sticking to the top and now just randomly floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem on my older project by adding launch screen.

Try this if you are missing launch screen:

1. Add a new launch screen by going to File -> New -> File... -> Launch
   Screen
2. Make sure the newly added `LaunchScreen.storyboard` is selected as
   the launch screen file under project settings.

to check this follow this steps:

1)Choose your project name in Xcode. 2)Select your project target. 3)Then select app icons and launch images and choose your newly added `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the age of the app I suspect it uses fixed sizes or size classes for its layout?

You will need to update the code that controls the layout.  If the design is simple and vertical based, you may be able to a 'quick and dirty" solution by embedding everything in a stack view.  However you should really update your code and/or storyboard to use Autolayout.  This will fix the current problem and ensure it will work with future devices of different sizes.